# Celery + RabbitMQ, some AMQP temporay queues not expiring

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery + rabbitmq setup with a busy django site, in the celery setting I have this config:

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"

CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 5

I am monitoring the queues with the "watch" command, what I have observed is whilst most of the temporary queues get deleled after a few seconds, there are some queues (same guid) did not get deleted, and the list grows slowly, regardless how many workers used.

The django site does generate about 60 tasks per second, accepts various information and use the tasks to digest information. The whole setup runs on a 16 core cpu server with plenty of RAM. Would this still caused by performance issue or a celery bug?

Cheers

James